# Question about the notion/definition of "isolated local minimizer".

Tags: optimization, definition, numerical-optimization

In Nocedal and Wright's optimization book, it defines,

> [image]

Observe that the isolated local minimizer is defined as a local minimizer, therefore, if $x^\star$ is a local isolated minimizer, there exists a neighborhood $\mathcal{N}$ of $x^\star$ such that $f(x^\star) \leq f(x), \forall x \in \mathcal{N}$ and $x^\star$ is the only local minimizer in $\mathcal{N}$.

But the $\leq$ doesn't make any sense, because it is *isolated*, therefore for all $x \in \mathcal{N}, x \neq x^\star$, $f(x^\star) < f(x)$.

So why is isolated local minimizer defined as a local minimizer, instead of as a "unique strict local minimizer"? It just seems that defining as a local minimizer instead of a strict local minimizer seems to be redundant if not unnecessary/confusing.

Comment: I don't see the difference between strict and isolated?

Comment: @copper.hat Apparently a strict local minimizer could be smaller than all other minimizers in a neighborhood, but the graph of the function oscillates so much around the strict one that other minimizers are essentially dense in the neighborhood, hence you cannot isolate it. Example is $x^4 cos(1/x) + 2x^4$.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: My point is that the definition of an isolated local minimizer should be defined completely with respect to the notion of a "strict local minimizer" instead of "local minimizer". The phrase "the only local minimizer" seems to be poorly worded. But I am also wondering if there is a reason why it is not defined with respect to strict local minimizer.

Comment: There may be a sequence of local minimisers $x_k$ converging to $x^*$ but each $f(x_k) > f(x^*)$. Then $x^*$ is strict but not isolated. (You could also have the $x_k$ satisfy $f(x_k) = f(x^*)$ so $x^*$ is neither strict nor isolated.)

Comment: So, isolated implies strict, but not the other way around.

Comment: @copper.hat Hi, I'm not saying that these two definitions should be equivalent. I am saying that the definition of "isolated local minimizer" should be defined with respect to "strict local minimizer", rather than "local minimizer" as is shown, i.e.,"...such that $x^\star$ is the only local minimizer." (See definition). It should be re-written as "...such that $x^\star$ is the only *strict* local minimizer."

Comment: It would be more clear, but it is equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us compare the following definitions.

> (Definition 1) A point $x^*$ is an isolated local minimizer if 
>   there is a neighborhood $\mathcal N$ of $x^*$ such that $x^*$ is 
>   the only local minimizer in $\mathcal N$.
>
> (Definition 2) A point $x^*$ is an isolated local minimizer if 
>   there is a neighborhood $\mathcal N$ of $x^*$ such that $x^*$ is 
>   the only *strict* local minimizer in $\mathcal N$.

You seem to imply that these definitions are equivalent.
However, this is not true.

Consider a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that
$0$ is a strict local minimizer but not an isolated minimizer
(such a function exists according to your comment).
Now, we define the function
$$
g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R,
\qquad x \mapsto f(\|x\|).
$$
It can be seen that $(0,0)$ is a strict local minimizer of $g$.
It can also be seen that $(0,0)$ is not an isolated minimizer
(in the sense of Definition 1).
However, other than $(0,0)$ there are no *isolated* local minimizers
in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$:
If $y\neq (0,0)$ is a local minimizer, then there are values
$z$ in each neighborhood of $y$ such that $\|y\|=\|z\|$
and therefore $g(y)=g(z)$.
So $(0,0)$ is not an isolated local minimizer in the sense of Definition 2.

Since Definition 1 allows for a wider class of local minimizers,
it can be applied more often, i.e. Theorems that use it in their assumptions 
are stronger.